# apply(datamatrix, 1, mean): dim(X) must have a positive length

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, apply, mean

I would like to calculate the following command:

```
scale.data<-as.matrix((datamatrix-apply(datamatrix,1,mean))/apply(datamatrix,1,sd))
```

However return this error:

> Error in apply(datamatrix, 1, mean): dim(X) must have a positive
> length Traceback:
>
> 1. apply(datamatrix, 1, mean)
> 2. stop("dim(X) must have a positive length")

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. The inclusion of a reproducible example would make it easier to help. [Link for guidance on asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: please provide a reproducible example of datamatrix, using dput(datamatrix) and paste the data in your question

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the transpose operator `t()`, and your code is supposed to be

```
scale.data<-as.matrix((datamatrix-t(apply(datamatrix,1,mean))/apply(datamatrix,1,sd)))
```

Comment: @SeforaNaomiAgrò then, please provide a reproducible example of `datamatrix`, using `dput(datamatrix)` and paste the data in your question

Comment: It is not good because return the same error. 
apply(datamatrix, 1, mean) -> dim(X) must have a positive length
I try to calculate the mean in another way, like mean(datamatrix), but I didn't get a result.